# Leaflet polygons showing on desktop but not on android

Tags: leaflet

I have an OpenStreetMap map and I'm using the leaflet library and everything works good on the website when I visit it from my laptop, but when I enter from my phone the map loads but the polygons aren't showing and the other leaflet buttons I put such as mapCenterCoord and others aren't loading. When I enter the website from my iPad, the map isn't loading at all! Just white space. Does anyone know how to fix this? Here are the pictures and my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9j2V.jpg
Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var mymap = L.map('map').setView([58.229553, -6.206524], 9);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors</a>',
      minZoom: 3,
      maxZoom: 14,
      zoomControl: true
    }).addTo(mymap);

    function add_geojson_layer(name, color="red") {

      var ll = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("geojson_files/1935_10_02/"+name+".geojson");

    ll.on('data:loaded', function() {
      ll.setStyle({
        color: color
      });
      ll.addTo(mymap);
    });
    }

    /***** COLORS *****/
    var axis = 'black'
    var axis_puppet = '#666666'
    var axis_occupied = '#a1a1a1'

    var allies = '#296d98'
    var allies_puppet = '#3792cb'
    var allies_occupied = '#45b6fe'

    var comintern = '#B30000'
    var comintern_puppet = 'red'
    var comintern_occupied = '#ff7f7f'

    var finland = 'purple'
    var finland_occupied = '#ac68cc'

    var neutral = '#ffca8a'
    var neutral_zone = 'white'


    var countries = [
      ["neutral_zone_iraq", neutral_zone],

      ["andorra", neutral],
      ["albania", neutral],
      ["bhutan", neutral],
      ["czechoslovakia", neutral],
      ["finland", neutral],
      ["danzig", neutral],
      ["greece", neutral],
      ["iraq", neutral],
      ["lichtenstein", neutral],
      ["luxembourg", neutral],
      ["poland", neutral],
      ["portugal", neutral],
      ["romania", neutral],
      ["spanish_africa", neutral],
      ["spanish_sahara", neutral],
      ["turkey", neutral],
      ["yugoslavia", neutral],

      ["bahrain", allies_puppet],
      ["bermuda", allies_puppet],
      ["british_africa", allies_puppet],
      ["british_somaliland", allies_puppet],
      ["cyprus", allies_puppet],
      ["djibouti", allies_puppet],
      ["france", allies],
      ["french_africa", allies_puppet],
      ["french_syria", allies_puppet],
      ["gambia", allies_puppet],
      ["gibraltar", allies_puppet],
      ["kuwait", allies_puppet],
      ["malta", allies_puppet],
      ["qatar", allies_puppet],
      ["south_georgia", allies_puppet],
      ["swaziland", allies_puppet],
      ["uk", allies],

      ["mongolia", comintern_puppet],
      ["tannu_tuva", comintern_puppet],
      ["ussr", comintern],

      ["eritrea", axis_puppet],
      ["german_prussia", axis],
      ["germany", axis],
      ["italian_dodecanese", axis],
      ["libya", axis_puppet],
      ["zara", axis]
    ]

    for (country of countries) {
      add_geojson_layer(country[0], country[1]);
    }

    L.control.mapCenterCoord({
      icon: false,
      position: 'bottomright',
      latlngFormat: 'DMS'
    }).addTo(mymap);
</script>
```

Comment: What happens when you resize your window? On your phone, changing the orientation might fire the resize event as well.

Comment: @ghybs When I resize the window / change orientation map is still there, that's not the problem, but on laptop the geojson layers / polygons are showing up, and they arent showing up on mobile.

Comment: Any errors on your dev console, either in desktop or remote debugging on android?

Comment: No, no errors at all. @IvanSanchez

Comment: I don't know if this helps, maybe the default value of the function makes problems: `add_geojson_layer(name, color="red")` change to `add_geojson_layer(name,color)` Or try to add only 1 polygon.

Comment: @FalkeDesign I tried both, none seems to help.

Comment: Sounds like there is not enough information to provide you with relevant help. Make sure to provide enough details for people to be able to reproduce your issue. Sharing a live reproduction example would surely help.

Comment: BTW how big are your GeoJSON files?

Comment: @ghybs Here, I made a tunnel for the website. http://6a671ba3.ngrok.io/map.php

Comment: @ghybs Most are like 1-5kb, but i have a few that are like 30kb

Comment: Actually, never mind, I solved the issue, it was apparently the issue that when I was including a javascript file I misspelled the location of the file... Oops...